# Postgresql nextval

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
nextval('productgallery_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Делаю данную запись в бд, чтобы каждый раз инкрементировать ID при создании новой записи. Но выдаётся ошибка.

```
SQL Error[42P01]: ERROR: relation "productgallery_id_seq" does not exist
```

Comment: Судя по сообщению последовательности productgallery_id_seq не существует. И непонятно зачем явно задавать тип, если `nextval` прекрасно принимает имя последовательности в форме строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextval('productgallery_id_seq'::regclass)` - проверьте, чтобы имя таблицы совпадало с тем, что вы прописываете в скобках

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят - нужно было сделать:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE productgallery_id_seq
```

Answer (score 0):

Понимать как работают последовательности в многопользовательской среде и как настраиваются думаю полезно, но каждый раз лезть под капот в общем то не обязательно для этих целей в PostgreSQL созданы три сурогатных типа использование которых автоматизируют создание полей автоинкремента:
[Serisl BigSerial](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/datatype-numeric#datatype-serial)